# Keystone.js - Displaying Blog Categories on Index Page

Tags: express, keystonejs

On my Blog and Post pages I am able to display the categories list by using:

```
{{# each data.post.categories }}
    <div class="tag-cloud">
    <a href="{{categoryUrl key}}">{{name}}</a>
    </div>              
{{/each}}
```

However the same exact code on the index view does not do anything (no errors, this section just displays as empty when I run keystone).

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the corresponding code in your routes.

If you look in `routes/views/blog.js` you'll find some code which sets `locals.posts.categories`, and this is then accessed as `data.posts.categories` in your view.

Try to replicate the necessary bits of this code in `routes/views/index.js`. It sounds like you don't need the actual posts, just the list of categories, so you'll only need some of the code from the blog route.

If you're still struggling I can give you more explicit code, but hopefully you should be able to figure it out on the blog.

Comment: Hi Jake! Thanks.  I found the line of code I was missing. I simply had to add "var async = require('async');" and it worked!